# Copy files in RPM spec files using micro %install

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have problem with RPM spec file. I need to copy huge number of files located under tar.gz file:

```
%install
mkdir -p ${buildroot}/opt/agent
install -m 0755 -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/agent
install -m 0777 * $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/agent
```

The question is how I have to configure this micro to copy all files under /opt/agent into the new RPM file?

Comment: Copy all files from the host's `/opt/agent` directory into the `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/agent` directory?

Comment: I'd pick one of `%{buildroot}` (and yes, it is `%{buildroot}` not `${buildroot}`) or `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` and stick with it. Also there's no need for `mkdir -p` if you are going to use `install -d` like that.